# How to use a custom body_class as a condition?

Tags: body-class

I am using a plugin that works great apart from the fact the breadcrumb is messed up. I would like to either try to ovveride the breadcrumb or remove it completely if I don't succeed.

I am using that plugin with a custom category-slug.php file but "because of the plugin" I cannot target that page anymore using is_category because a kind of new page is generated.

I have added a custom body_class to that new page in order to be able to style it with css.

I was wondering if it was possible to use the custom body_class to target that page in functions, hooks or filters :

Something like

```
if ( body_class = 'my-class') {

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the plugin that's stopping `is_category()` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
$body_css_classes = get_body_class();

if ( in_array( 'my-class', $body_css_classes ) ) {
     /* DO THIS */
} else {
     /* DO THAT */
}
```

For more details please [check this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class).